Can't install CUDA 12.1 in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Here is my system details:
x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

But this installation keeps giving me lots of gcc compilation errors, like:
from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:56,
from /tmp/selfgz3982/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-530.30.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-lock.h:29,
from /tmp/selfgz3982/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-530.30.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:32,
from /tmp/selfgz3982/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-530.30.02/kernel/nvidia/nv-procfs.c:27:
/tmp/selfgz3982/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-530.30.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-mm.h: In function 'NV_GET_USER_PAGES':
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:44:17: warning: passing argument 1 of 'get_user_pages' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
44 | #define current get_current()
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
| |
| struct task_struct *
/tmp/selfgz3982/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-530.30.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-mm.h:88:31: note: in expansion of macro 'current'
88 | return get_user_pages(current, current->mm, start, nr_pages, write,
| ^~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:44:17: warning: passing argument 1 of 'get_user_pages' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
44 | #define current get_current()
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
| |
| struct task_struct *
/tmp/selfgz3982/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-530.30.02/kernel/common/inc/nv-mm.h:88:31: note: in expansion of macro 'current'
88 | return get_user_pages(current, current->mm, start, nr_pages, write,
| ^~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:44:17: warning: passing argument 1 of 'get_user_pages' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
44 | #define current get_current()
...
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic/Makefile:2039: /tmp/selfgz10069/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-530.30.02/kernel] Error 2

Full log can be found at: https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/10d68d94fb83f16dfb4caf2e6e7cb982
What shall I do? Can you guys please help?

It may help to have the actual command that produced this output added to the question.

@David I had run sudo sh cuda_12.1.1_530.30.02_linux.run

Do not add this to comments add to the question please. So everyone can see it right off. Also please add what is in the .sh file. No one is going to go search for the info.

See answers 1077061 and 1219761 for installing cuda without messing up existing working Nvidia installs. Just use the .run script to unpack into non-system directories (options to override the /bin and /lib dirs to be the cuda/bin and cuda/lib).

Though i cannot pinpoint the cause of the compilation error you might want to give a shot to the local debian package on Nvidia's site,it would probably work.
Edit:The run does give an error as

warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0

I am not sure why does it report this as both of the above must refer to the same compiler,on futher investigation source,seems as if the cc compiler doesn't follow some revised compilation guidelines.
You might be able to force the runfile to use gcc instead of cc(again i don't know why does it use the 'cc' compiler) by temporarily exporting the cc varibale to gcc as export CC=/usr/bin/gcc and then executing the runfile.
gcc-12 and gcc-12-x86-64-linux-gnu are listed as separate packages.
all the semingly different GNU compilers are just symlinks on modern linux.
